# Как скрыть метод базового класса?

Tags: c#, generics

У меня есть класс WsEvent:

```
internal class WsEvent
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public void Invoke() {}
}
```

И есть его обобщенный наследник:

```
internal class WsEvent<T> : WsEvent
{
    public T EventData { get; private set; }

    public void Invoke(T Data) {}
}
```

Я хотел бы скрыть метод Invoke() базового класса при использовании обобщенного класса. Сейчас IntelliSens подсказывает, что у экземпляра обобщенного класса есть перегруженный метод Invoke() и Invoke(T). Я хочу что бы был только Invoke(T).

Может быть подход целиком не правильный. Я в попытках методом тыка изучить обобщенные классы)

Comment: скрыть никак, только если не наследоваться от него

Comment: Печально. Ладно. Оформите в виде ответа. Поставлю галку)

Comment: Только если сделать его protected или private - тогда перегрузки вне этих классов не будет

Comment: Можно этот класс написать на Visual Basic :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Выделите интерфейс:

```
interface IWsEvent
{
    string Name { get; }
    void Invoke();
}

interface IWsEvent<T> : IWsEvent
{
    T EventData { get; }
    void Invoke(T Data);
}
```

И реализуйте нужный метод явно:

```
class WsEvent : IWsEvent
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public void Invoke() { }
}

class WsEvent<T> : IWsEvent<T>
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    void IWsEvent.Invoke() { } // <== явная реализация
    public T EventData { get; private set; }
    public void Invoke(T Data) { }
}
```

Comment: Автору же нужно скрыть метод, а не явно реализовать.

Comment: скрыть от `IntelliSense`? Это сработает как раз именно так

Comment: хах, я опять поспешил и недочитал вопрос :)

Answer (score 3):

Скрыть базовые методы невозможно. Но можно не наследоваться от не-обобщенного типа ИЛИ можно ввести вместо этого 2 интерфейса - обобщенный и не-обобщенный. Старые типы при этом реализуют не-обобщенный интерфейс, новые - обобщенный. И интерфейсы уже наследуйте как хотите.

Например, MS для [`IEnumerable<T>`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/ienumerable.cs,3acf01620172c7f0) выбрали наследование от `IEnumerable`. Но, так как вы хотите иное, то вы не должны так наследовать, и для вас обобщенный и не-обобщенный интерфейсы будут не связаны друг с другом.